# How do I convert data from a URL/API into a table in node.js express using jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

**I've tried this in the index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  request('https://status.heroku.com/api/v3/issues?since=2012-04-24&limit=1',  function (error, response, body) {
     res.render('index', {
        title : 'oded',
        heroku: body}
     );

  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**And this in index.pug:**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{body}
```

That is even before talking about the conversion to a table. Just wanted to see the data itself. Tried numerous techniques I found online but none worked for me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you unable to fetch data from Heroku or unable to render on `index.pug`?

Comment: I am sure the data is fetched from Heroku. I am not sure what the correct terminology is but I am not able to use the data in my index.pug.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your response object using field named **heroku**. Refer this snippet

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    table
      tr
        th id
        th title
      each data in heroku       
        tr
          td data.id
          td data.title
```